# How to use Retrofit 2 and Gson to model data where the JSON response "keys" change frequently

Tags: android, plot, retrofit2, gson

In an Android app, I am trying to use **Retrofit 2/Gson** to retrieve the data in this JSON response. "bpi" in the JSON response contains a bunch of key/value pairs where the keys are **dates**.

**What is a good way to model my classes to store this data?** (I want to eventually plot the data.)

I know about http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ but the output will not work since the JSON "keys" change daily.

**The JSON response returns Date/value pairs over the last 31 days:**

```
{
  "bpi": {
    "2017-11-30": 9916.5363,
    "2017-12-01": 10859.5625,
    "2017-12-02": 10895.0138,
    "2017-12-03": 11180.8875,
    "2017-12-04": 11616.855,
    "2017-12-05": 11696.0583,
    "2017-12-06": 13708.9913,
    "2017-12-07": 16858.02,
    "2017-12-08": 16057.145,
    "2017-12-09": 14913.4038,
    "2017-12-10": 15036.9563,
    "2017-12-11": 16699.6775,
    "2017-12-12": 17178.1025,
    "2017-12-13": 16407.2025,
    "2017-12-14": 16531.0838,
    "2017-12-15": 17601.9438,
    "2017-12-16": 19343.04,
    "2017-12-17": 19086.6438,
    "2017-12-18": 18960.5225,
    "2017-12-19": 17608.35,
    "2017-12-20": 16454.7225,
    "2017-12-21": 15561.05,
    "2017-12-22": 13857.145,
    "2017-12-23": 14548.71,
    "2017-12-24": 13975.4363,
    "2017-12-25": 13917.0275,
    "2017-12-26": 15745.2575,
    "2017-12-27": 15378.285,
    "2017-12-28": 14428.76,
    "2017-12-29": 14427.87,
    "2017-12-30": 12629.8138
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use GSON for that kind of data.
GSON requires final key names.

I'd let Retrofit parse it as a JSONObject, and then manually find the "bpi" object, and loop over each of the children, then creating my own objects which contain the date and the value. (Or store them in a HashMap if you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

You can read data as hash map
Declare your bpi object like this:

```
@SerializedName("bpi")
public final JsonElement bpi;
```

and parse it :

```
public HashMap<String, String> getDataFromJson(final JsonElement bpi) {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {
    }.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(bpi, listType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [custom deserializer](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics) to manually parse the incoming Json data according to your own logic. Then, tell Retrofit to use it with the method [`addConverterFactory`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html#addConverterFactory-retrofit2.Converter.Factory-).

First, create a `JsonDeserializer<MyType>` like so (the logic within is only an example):

```
JsonDeserializer<MyType> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>() {  
    @Override
    public MyType deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

        JsonObject bpiObject = jsonObject.get("bpi").getAsJsonObject();
        Map<Date, Float> data = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : bpiObject.entrySet()) {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(entry.getKey());
            float value = entry.getValue().getAsFloat();
            data.put(date, value)
        }

        return new MyType(data);
    }
};
```

Then, create your Gson object and register your deserializer:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(MyType.class, deserializer);
        .create();
```

Finally, create your Retrofit instance like so:

```
MyApi api = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(gson)
        .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
        .build()
        .create(MyApi.class)
```

where `MyApi` is your Retrofit API interface.